# VBA scattered userform on dual screen (Laptop 17" vs screen 27")

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm having this strange issue when showing a userform on dual screen with different sizes (even though they're both 1920 x 1080)

So I hooked my 17" laptop to a samsung 27" monitor.

I use the very well known code on initialize:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  Me.StartUpPosition = 0
  Me.Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * Me.Width)
  Me.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * Me.Height)

End Sub
```

This works as it should be if I hook 2 monitors to my laptop and close the laptop.

However if my Laptop is open and I load the userform, all controls seems to be off place.
The thing is this only happens when the application is active on the monitor, if it is open on the laptop everything is displayed correctly

Image of design mode:
[image: Design mode image]

When the userform is loaded, it looks like this:
[image: Show image]

When I drag the userform around (just 1 pixel) the userform shows correctly:
[image: Image after dragging]

Is there anyway to fix this?
I tried several things like re setting the widths and heights of every control on initialize codewise and so on without any success.

Looked around on google for like 3 hours and can't find any method to help me.

maybe one you Pro's has the magic solution?

Thanks in advance,
Kind regards!

Comment: Try adding this line in the form Initialize event: `Me.left = Me.left + 1: Me.Repaint `

Comment: Hi FaneDuru,
I tried it without succes, not on the end of the sub nor in the beginning.
If I add a commandbutton with the same code and click it, it does what it is supposed to do. If I call CommandButton1_Click on initialize it's not working

Comment: Just added the same code to UserForm_Activate() and this does the trick

Answer (score 0):

FaneDuru sugestion worked,
but instead of putting it in the initialize event, you need to put the code in the activate event

Comment: Yes! It is the last called event... Glad you solved your problem!